# Arch Linux USB Installer Infinite Loop & How to Properly Partition a UEFI Disk Before Installing Arch Linux

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, arch-linux, uefi

I would like to install Arch Linux and am familiar with GParted and its use. However, my computer comes with Windows on it, along with an EFI system partition on `/dev/sda2`. This seems to be a pretty inconvenient place for it, since it has a 1GB partition just before it.

My question is, would it be best to format the partition and attempt to move it to the left, then install my partitions, or to make a new partition table? Is it even necessary to format it, if I follow the first option? Thanks for your help. I'm new to Arch Linux, although not to Linux, and want to get this right so as to avoid hours of troubleshooting.

Additonally, I do not care about preserving other partitions, such as those specific to Windows. I want the whole disk to be dedicated to Arch Linux.

#### Edit:

I got the partitions set up from scratch, but now my USB stick won't work. Specifically, it boots up, lets me go into the UEFI installer, gives me a black screen for a second, and reboots into itself. Then, it repeats the process. What is wrong with my USB stick?

I set it up using `dd`, using the command `sudo dd bs=4M if=Downloads/archlinux-2014.01.05-dual.iso of=/dev/sdd && sync`. I'm afraid I have to use a USB stick since my laptop lacks an optical drive.

Comment: If you don't care about any of the data just delete the partitions you want and recreate them.

Comment: Is it safe to delete and recreate the EFI system partition, then recreate that? Or, would I have trouble booting if I did that?

Comment: Its perfectly normally to install Arch Linux on a HDD without any partitions.

Comment: Thanks. I set up the partitions from scratch and installed an iso to my USB using `dd` (I have to use a USB since I don't have an optical drive). However, selecting the default UEFI option now gives me a black screen for a second, then reboots into the USB, and repeats. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Are you the required EFI files exist on the EFI System Partition?

Comment: I didn't add any files. I just created a FAT32 partition and flagged it with `boot` in GParted. Is there another step I need to perform?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I've given up and installed Xubuntu, although I'll be sure to remove XFCE. Every time I tried to burn to a USB, no matter what tool, something went wrong. I even destroyed one of my disks.